# How to reverse the cascade?

Tags: html, css

I have a link element ( dynamically generated ) inside a div element inside another div element.

I need the width of the link element to propagate up the cascade and set the width of the outer div.

This is kind of the opposite of how CSS works.  But the content is dynamically generated and I need it encapsulated.

Is there a strategy to do this?

Here is a screen shot of the debugger code.

[image]

Basically the content of the a tag should set the width and this width should be the width of the outer div.

Comment: Set the `display` of the `div` elements to `inline-block`, then they have the width of their content.

Comment: what happens when you don't set any width parameters for the divs in CSS?

Comment: ... I took out all the width properties and it somehow gives the `a` tag a width of 21px which breaks text longer than that ...

Comment: Here is a start on a fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/tepue2xo/

Comment: I don't see the 21px problem in your fiddle. In fact, if I add @t.niese's solution, it seems to work as you want. https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/tepue2xo/1/

Comment: ... the content needs to stack vertically though.